# SSH Terminal width when run from plink.exe on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, console, plink

I'm using Console2 to run a Powershell in which I run plink.exe to connect to a Linux server. It works fine except that ps, top and other utilities in the shell only thinks the output window is 80 characters wide, while the window really is about 200 characters wide. How can I get them to detect the real console size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plink` is designed to be used as a transport for binary data – it doesn't ask the server to allocate a "pseudo-terminal" (pty) and doesn't forward the dimensions of the local terminal.

(The 'ssh' client also does the same when run in "batch" mode, as a pseudo-terminal would actually corrupt binary data transferred through it.)

If you want a full-featured console-based SSH client, <del>install Cygwin OpenSSH</del> use the built-in Windows OpenSSH `ssh.exe`.

(At the time of writing this post in 2012, the Windows Console did not provide any sort of terminal emulation, so even if plink *did* request the server to allocate a pseudo-terminal, none of your full-screen programs would've worked correctly anyway – the terminal control sequences would just show up as garbage on-screen.

The Cygwin variant of OpenSSH dealt with this by relying on the Cygwin runtime to "magically" translate the control sequences into appropriate Windows console operations, while PuTTY's `plink` had nothing like that.

This only changed with Windows 8.1 and later Windows 10, which *do* support Unix-style terminal sequences, although plink still does not allocate a pty – the answer remains "use OpenSSH".)

Comment: Hm, I don't understand that. In Console2.exe (the console) I'm running PowerShell.exe (the shell) running plink.exe (ssh transport) to connect to a server. Isn't that analoguous to gnome-terminal running bash running ssh? If it works on a Linux client, why not on a Windows one?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: It *is* somewhat analogous. The most important difference is that unlike GNOME Terminal, the [Windows console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) does not process ANSI/VT220 escape sequences; instead, programs call special functions, somewhat like ioctls, on the console handle, to change text format or move cursor. When using Cygwin programs (such as Cygwin OpenSSH) the cygwin1 runtime performs this sequence -> API translation automatically; when using native Win32 programs (such as plink) this does not happen.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: Another difference is that the `plink` client, having been written with **batch usage** in mind, does not by default allocate a TTY on the server side, making it impossible for remote programs to find out the screen size. (Full-screen programs use special ioctl's on their output device if it is a tty; they cannot do so on simple pipes when there is no tty.) Even if you use `plink -t` forcing the TTY allocation, plink does not forward the actual console size -- it always sets a generic 80x25. On the other hand, OpenSSH has the same client for both batch and interactive usage.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: Side note: Console2.exe is not the actual console; it is only a thin GUI wrapper around a hidden Windows Console window, reading its screen buffer periodically; it cannot add new functionality to the console (such as ANSI/VT220 support), and it cannot modify the way *plink* and other console programs work.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer's been accepted, but let me just mention that PuTTY itself will bring up a proper terminal emulator without the issues OP had mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `putty` to configure the Window size, which `plink` will then recognize.  I have sent a patch to the PuTTY developers which makes `plink` use the current console width (at startup, it won't recognize resizing).  **Update**: they have refused the patch, saying plink is not meant for interactive use. **Update2**: [custom plink](http://plink.adoxa.cjb.net/).

Answer (score 0):

On the Linux side, what's your shell?

If it's bash (which I assume it is) you can tell bash to update it's idea of what the window size is

put:

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

into your Linux $HOME/.bashrc. I'm not sure what the equivalent would be for zsh

Comment: FYI, `checkwinsize` merely causes $ROWS/$COLUMNS to be updated, and such full-screen utilities as `top` do not depend on these variables -- they query the tty device directly.